# I encountered a "You don't have write permissions" error when installing an older version of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

I have read the related answers, but the content is too complicated and I am not sure how to do it.

Since I inherited an old project, I need to use Ruby version 2.3.1, I cannot install the latest version of Ruby, nor can I install the latest version of Rails (must match the Ruby version).

I installed Rails under the following instructions on the MacOS terminal:

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.2
```

But after a few lines of messages, an error message appears as follows

```
While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)

     You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

I'm not sure if I chose the wrong version of Rails, or there are other operational errors. Please tell me what should I do?

I just moved from Windows to MacOS.

Comment: I did install RVM, I can use `$rvm list` to see all installed Ruby, and use `$rvm use` to select the version. I currently only install 2.3.1, should I install other versions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added "--user-install" at the end of the original instruction to proceed to the next step:

`gem install rails -v 4.2.2 --user-install`